# run matlab script from php code in windows xp

Tags: php, matlab

I have made a simulation in matlab for RC circuit. I can run this code from command prompt by typing:

`"C:\Documents and Settings\User\RC>matlab -r filename "`   OR `"C:\MATLAB\R2008b\bin\RC>matlab -r filename"`  in Windows XP.

I'm trying to run this matlab file through php code(which will start the execution and sends back the plot in an image file). I've used  `shell_exec();`  in php code.

i.e:

```
<?php
         shell_exec('C:\MATLAB\R2008b\bin\RC>matlab -r filename');
?>
```

But could not run the script. PLEASE HELP ME HOW TO DO THIS.

Comment: Did you install PHP ?